# Problem importing with read.csv (NULL in database manager is not recognized)

Tags: r, csv, encoding

I'm trying to import a dataframe to r with read.csv. I exported from my database manager (DBeaver) with UTF-8 encoding.

In some factor vectors what is NULL in the database manager is not recognized as so. I think NULL is replaced by blank space(s) and I when I try, can't turn them to NULL or NA.

I'm using:

```
tb1 <- read.csv("pacientes.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".")
```

I identified the problem when I use

```
table(tb1$var2, useNA="ifany")
```

With factor variables I know have missing values and I get a table with "blank space(s)" as a category (along with the correct categories)

I have 59 columns, so using some features of read.csv is unpractical. And I really believe there's an easier way to fix the problem. Can anyone help me? thank you very much!

Comment: There is an `na.strings` argument in `read.table` and thus also in `read.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
read.csv("pacientes.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".", na.strings = c("NA", "", " "))
```

Comment: I put whitespace (`" "`) and empty string (`""`) in the `na.string` argument - wasn't sure, what exactly you meant by "blank space".

Comment: Great. Mark it as the answer then and if you want give it an upvote.